# SQL Error Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception

Tags: php, sql, database

Please, help me! :(
I want to add datas in 2 tables, but i have a problem. Datas didn't add and sql didn't want to work :(

> Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for
>   the right syntax to use near ' AND `id_status` = 1' at line 4 in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\medhelper\www\task_add.php:243 Stack trace: #0
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\medhelper\www\task_add.php(243):
>   mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), '\r\n S...') #1 {main} thrown in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\medhelper\www\task_add.php on line 243

PHP

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
require_once 'functions.php';
$db = get_connect();

    if(empty($_POST)){
        //Пользователь перешел по ссылке
        $task = [];
        $patient = [];

        if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
            // получаем инфу по вызову и пациенту с конкретным id
            $id = (int)$_GET['id'];
            $task_q = mysqli_query($db, "
                SELECT *
                FROM `task`
                WHERE `id` = {$id}
            ;");
            $task = mysqli_fetch_assoc($task_q);


            $patient_q = mysqli_query($db, "
                SELECT *
                FROM `patient`
                WHERE `id` = {$id}
            ;");
            $patient = mysqli_fetch_assoc($patient_q);

        } else {
            // делаем заглушку для book
    //        $book_q = mysqli_query($db, "
    //            SHOW COLUMNS FROM `book`
    //        ;");
    //        $book = mysqli_fetch_assoc($book_q);
        }



        $status_q = mysqli_query($db, "
            SELECT * FROM `status` ORDER BY `name`
        ;");
        $statuses = mysqli_fetch_all($status_q, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        $user_q = mysqli_query($db, "
            SELECT CONCAT (`user`.name, ' ', `user`.surname , ' ', `user`.m_name) as u_fullname
            FROM `user`
            WHERE `id_role` = 3 
            ORDER BY `u_fullname`
           ;");

        $users = mysqli_fetch_all($user_q, MYSQLI_ASSOC);


        view_init('header');
        view_init('sidebar');
        view_init('top_nav');
        view_init('task_add', [
            'task' => $task,
            'patient' => $patient,
            'users' => $users,
            'statuses' => $statuses
        ]);
        view_init('footer');


    } else {
        // пользователь отправил форму по пациенту
        $name = escape($_POST['name']);
        $surname = escape($_POST['surname']);
        $m_name = escape($_POST['m_name']);
        $gender = $_POST['gender'];
        $dob = (int)($_POST['dob']);
        $address = escape($_POST['address']);
        $tel= (int)($_POST['tel']);
        $id = (int)$_POST['id'];

        // по задаче
        $diagnosis= (int)($_POST['diagnosis']);
        $id_user = (int)($_POST['diagnosis']);
        $id_status = (int)($_POST['status']);
        $id = (int)$_POST['id'];

        if ($id) {
            // редактирование книги
            mysqli_query($db, "
                UPDATE `patient` SET
                 `name` = '{$name}',
                `surname` = '{$surname}',
                `m_name` = '{$m_name}',
                `gender` = '{$gender}',
                `dob` = {$dob},
                `address` = '{$address}',
                `tel` = {$tel}
                WHERE `id` = {$id}
                ;");


            mysqli_query($db, "
            UPDATE `task` SET
                `diagnosis` = '{$diagnosis}',
                `id_user` = {$id_user},
                `id_status` = {$id_status},
                `id_patient` = {$id_patient}
                WHERE `id` = {$id}
            ;");


        } else {
            // добавление новой задачи
            $query_t = mysqli_query($db, "
                SELECT `id`
                FROM `task`
                WHERE `diagnosis` = '{$diagnosis}'
                  AND `id_user` = {$id_user},
                  AND `id_status` = {$id_status}

            ;");


            $query_p = mysqli_query($db, "
                SELECT `id`
                FROM `patient`
                 WHERE `name` = '{$name}'
                  AND `surname` = '{$surname}',
                  AND `m_name` = '{$m_name}',
                  AND `gender` = '{$gender}',
                  AND `dob` = {$dob},
                  AND `address` = '{$address}',
                  AND `tel` = {$tel}


               ;");


            if (!mysqli_num_rows($query_t)) {
                mysqli_query($db, "
                    INSERT INTO `task` SET
                    `diagnosis` = '{$diagnosis}',
                    `id_status` = '{$id_status}',
                    `id_user` = '{$id_user}',
                    WHERE `id` = {$id}
                    ;");
            }

            elseif (!mysqli_num_rows($query_p)) {
                mysqli_query($db, "
                    INSERT INTO `patient` SET
                   `name` = '{$name}',
                   `surname` = '{$surname}',
                   `m_name` = '{$m_name}',
                   `gender` = '{$gender}',
                   `dob` = {$dob},
                   `address` = '{$address}',
                   `tel` = {$tel},
                   WHERE `id` = {$id}
                ;");
            }
        }
            if (mysqli_error($db)) {
                echo 'Вызов не был добавлен';
                //header('location:tasks.php');

            } else {
                echo 'Вызов добавлен';
            }

    }
```

Html template - form

```
 <form action="task_add.php" method="post" id="add">
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="personal">
        <div class="personal_info">
            <h4>Личные данные пациента</h4>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id"
                           value="<?= isset($patient['id']) ? $patient['id'] : '' ?>">

                    <label>Имя</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name"
                           class="form-control"
                           id="field"
                           placeholder="Имя">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group">
                    <label>Фамилия</label>
                    <input type="text" name="surname"
                           class="form-control"
                           id="field" placeholder="Фамилия">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group">
                    <label>Отчество</label>
                    <input type="text" name="m_name"
                           class="form-control" id="field"
                           placeholder="Отчество">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group">
                    <label>Дата рождения</label>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control"
                           id="field" name="dob">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                    <label>Пол</label>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="gender" id="optionsRadios1" value="1" checked>
                            Женский
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="gender" id="optionsRadios2" value="2">
                            Мужской
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="personal_address">
            <h4>Адрес и телефон</h4>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group">
                    <label>Адрес</label>
                    <input type="text" name="address"
                           class="form-control" id="field"
                           placeholder="Адрес">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group">
                    <label>Телефон</label>
                    <input type="number" name="tel"
                           class="form-control"
                           id="field" placeholder="Телефон">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="personal_doctor">
            <input type="hidden" name="id"
                   value="<?= isset($task['id']) ? $task['id'] : '' ?>">

            <h4>Жалобы</h4>
            <div class="cleaffix"></div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group">
                    <label>Жалобы</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control"
                           id="field" name="diagnosis">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group">
                    <label>Врач</label>
                    <select name="user" class="form-control">
                        <option id="user_blank">Выберите врача</option>
                        <? foreach ($users as $user): ?>
                        <option value="<?= $user['id'] ?>"
                        <?= isset($task['u_fullname']) && ($user['id'] == $task['u_fullname']) ? 'selected' : ''?>
                        >
                        <?= $user['u_fullname'] ?>
                        </option>
                    </select>
                    <? endforeach ?>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group">
                    <label>Статус вызова</label>
                    <select name="status" class="form-control">
                        <option id="status_blank">Выберите статус</option>
                        <? foreach ($statuses as $status): ?>
                        <option value="<?= $status['id'] ?>" <?= isset($task['id_status']) && ($status['id'] == $task['id_status']) ? 'selected' : ''?> >
                        <?= $status['name'] ?>
                        </option>
                        <? endforeach ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Отмена</button>
    <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Добавить</button>-->
    <input type="submit" value="Добавить" class="btn btn-primary">
</div>
```

Tables
Patient
[patient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvnbX.png)
Task
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyLbY.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no comma between AND conditions so this

```
AND `id_user` = {$id_user},
AND `id_status` = {$id_status}
```

should be written as

```
AND `id_user` = {$id_user} 
AND `id_status` = {$id_status}
```

> You have done this in a number of your queries, so you will need to check them all

There is also an error in your INSERT command here

```
INSERT INTO `patient` SET
            `name` = '{$name}',
            `surname` = '{$surname}',
            `m_name` = '{$m_name}',
            `gender` = '{$gender}',
            `dob` = {$dob},
            `address` = '{$address}',
            `tel` = {$tel},
 WHERE `id` = {$id}"
```

There is no `WHERE` clause on an INSERT Query, as you are creating a NEW row, not trying to find one to change. So the syntax is

```
INSERT INTO `patient` SET
            `name` = '{$name}',
            `surname` = '{$surname}',
            `m_name` = '{$m_name}',
            `gender` = '{$gender}',
            `dob` = {$dob},
            `address` = '{$address}',
            `tel` = {$tel}"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Unfortunately, i have another problem :D My datas added with id = 0. Do you know why it happened? And inputs didn't displayed in table :'(  error-> Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'